# Mackie's argument from queerness - identical argument can be made against universals?

Tags: moral-skepticism

So reading this argument for moral skepticism:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moral_nihilism#Argument_from_queerness

It seems to me like the identical argument can be made against universals. Is this indeed what Mackie would say or would Mackie say morality somehow more queer than universals? ie: does morality poses additional problems that universals don't?

Comment: Universals do not even come close in queerness, see [SEP](https://stanford.library.sydney.edu.au/archives/spr2017/entries/moral-anti-realism/moral-error-theory.html) for a better retelling. Universals are  neither imperatives nor vested with causal powers to enforce themselves objectively. What makes objective imperatives queer is that they are neither concrete nor abstract in any familiar way that would let us make sense of what "objective" means. That something can *move* to action without any causal connection to the actor is queer indeed.

Comment: Not sure about universals, but you might argue that logic is queer in Mackie's sense. Traditionally, logic is regarded as having some normative role, but it is not concrete and has no causal connection to the universe. Mackie would hardly accept that we should dispense with logic, so this might serve as a 'back at you' argument against him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that J. L. Mackie judged something to be too strange to exist is in the end just his personal taste.

I don’t think that realism about universals necessarily commits you to believing that universals have causal powers.

But yes, in many cases that much is admitted! Still universals, for modern realists à la D. M. Armstrong, are very different from e. g. Plato’s “Form of the Good”: They are empirically *verified,* like mass or electric charge.

If we say *“opposite charges attract”* and understand this literally, in a realist manner (electric charge being the universal), we’re still operating in a materialist, reductionist framework.

IMHO he implicitly or tacitly identified different “problematic” (from his perspective) philosophical positions

1. anti-reductionism
2. anti-materialism
3. teleology
4. belief in the  causal power of universals

on which moral realism depends on. And this all culminated in his argument of (unexplained) queerness.

If we ignore points 1. - 3.., then yes, you’re right: the fact that opposite charges attract is just analogous to “The Good” acting on humans.

Comment: Mackie does not use "queer" in the sense of "strange" broadly speaking, or in any sense that applies to anti-reductionism, anti-materialism or teleology (although he might have considered all of those strange). The word is used in a sense specific to objective imperatives only and applies regardless of his judgments.

Comment: @Conifold Mackie defines “queer” as “utterly different from anything else in the universe”; but his assessment of moral values being “utterly different” depends very much on what else he admits in his ontology. Of course “normal” universals would not act like moral values; the latter instead “supply the explanation for” or “ground” categorical imperatives (and can be resisted). But I don’t think that moral values are really “utterly different from anything else” in a non-materialist, teleological, holistic, etc. philosophy. They certainly aren’t if naturalism is rejected.

Comment: It makes no difference what Mackie has in *his* ontology, what matters is whether they have common analogs in ontologies generally. Non-materialist, teleological, holistic, etc., ontologies rarely propose self-acting objective values as well, they are reduced to something else, God, karma, etc. Even if they did, the issue is with objective values generally, not moral values specifically, so analogy of the latter to the former would not help. And even if his argument did specifically depend on naturalism that would still hardly make it a matter of his personal taste.